# How to reduce the quality of H264 Video

Tags: c++, video-streaming, live-streaming, libx264

How to reduce the quality of H264 video using libx264 library, for transmission over internet.

I want to reduce the quality, so that the frame size will become small and decreases the network latency while transferring over internet.

Comment: which language do you use? in which platform? consider video streaming instead of download play ?

Comment: hi Shivan, am developing this in C++ on windows and download play is not an solution as am streaming real time data.

Comment: Consider to use streaming server software. They will do this task for you :)

Comment: am developing the streaming sever to stream the video to my clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

X264 has many (many,many) parameters for controlling quality. What you really want to do is controll bit-rate. X264 has several rate controll mode you probably want to use X264_RC_ABR and set i_bitrate to whatever your bandwidth is. Take a look at the x264_param_t strut in x264.h for all the options.